# Python create dict from CSV and use the file name as key

Tags: python, file, dictionary, text

I have a simple CSV text file called "allMaps.txt". It contains the following:

```
cat, dog, fish
```

How can I take the file name "allMaps" and use it as a key, along with the contents being values?

I wish to achieve this format:

```
{"allMaps": "cat", "dog", "fish"}
```

**I have a range of txt files all containing values separated by commas so a more dynamic method that does it for all would be beneficial!**

The other txt files are:

```
allMaps.txt
fiveMaps.txt
tenMaps.txt
sevenMaps.txt
```

They all contain comma separated values. Is there a way to look into the folder and convert each one on the text files into a key-value dict?

Comment: Your output example is not a valid key-value dict. Should the value be a list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have the file names in a list.

```
files = ["allMaps.txt", "fiveMaps.txt", "tenMaps.txt", "sevenMaps.txt"]
```

You can do the following:

```
my_dict = {}
for file in files:
    with open(file) as f:
        items = [i.strip() for i in f.read().split(",")]
    my_dict[file.replace(".txt", "")] = items
```

If the files are all in the same folder, you could do the following instead of maintaining a list of files:

```
import os
files = os.listdir("<folder>")
```

Answer (score 1):

Given the file names, you can create a dictionary where the key stores the filenames with a corresponding value of a list of the file data:

```
files = ['allMaps.txt', 'fiveMaps.txt', 'tenMaps.txt', 'sevenMaps.txt']
final_results = {i:[b.strip('\n').split(', ') for b in open(i)] for i in files}
```